# Add to a Pandas DafaFrame, information from another DataFrame & in the right order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe like this :

```py
# FIRST DF
ROW_A    ROW_B
a        52
a        52
b        45
b        45
b        45
c        69
```

In a second dataframe :

```py
# SECOND DF
ROW_A    ROW_B    ROW_C    ROW_D
c        69       x        y
a        52       toto     tata
a        52       titi     tutu
b        45       hey      hi
b        45       hola     yo
b        45       slt      bjr
```

I want to put the second dataframe information on the 1st dataframe **in the correct order**, just like this :

```py
# FIRST DF
ROW_A    ROW_B    ROW_C    ROW_D
a        52       toto     tata
a        52       titi     tutu
b        45       hey      hi
b        45       hola     yo
b        45       slt      bjr
c        69       x        y
```

I tried this algorithm:

```py
for i in range(len(first_df)):
    row_a = first_df.iloc[i, 0]
    for y in range(len(second_df)):
        rw_a = second_df.iloc[y, 0]
        row_c = second_df.iloc[y, 2]
        row_d = second_df.iloc[y, 3]
        if row_a == rw_a:
            first_df[i, "ROW_C"] = row_c
            first_df[i, "ROW_D"] = row_d
```

This algo always put the last row information :

```py
# FIRST DF
ROW_A    ROW_B    ROW_C    ROW_D
a        52       titi     tutu
a        52       titi     tutu
b        45       slt      bjr
b        45       slt      bjr
b        45       slt      bjr
c        69       x        y
```

The objective is not to add columns but to add information according to each line. I don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `df.merge` with `df.drop_duplicates`:

```
In [2113]: output = df1.merge(df2).drop_duplicates()

In [2114]: output
Out[2114]: 
   ROW_A  ROW_B ROW_C ROW_D
0      a     52  toto  tata
1      a     52  titi  tutu
4      b     45   hey    hi
5      b     45  hola    yo
6      b     45   slt   bjr
13     c     69     x     y
```

Comment: Someone is very active on his notebook :-o (2114 *shift+enter* )

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I have this error : "ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat". What does it mean ?

Comment: @youngpj this means you probably have int for ROW_B in one DataFrame but strings in the other, make sure you have homogeneous types

Comment: @mozway thanks y'all, it works well now !

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, less sexy that that of @Mayank but more efficient if many duplicates:

```
cols = ['ROW_A', 'ROW_B']
(df1
 .assign(x=df1.groupby(cols).cumcount())
 .merge(df2.assign(x=df2.groupby(cols).cumcount()),
        on=cols+['x']
       )
 .drop('x', axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
  ROW_A  ROW_B ROW_C ROW_D
0     a     52  toto  tata
1     a     52  titi  tutu
2     b     45   hey    hi
3     b     45  hola    yo
4     b     45   slt   bjr
5     c     69     x     y
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What can I put in 'cols' variable ?

Comment: @youngpj sorry I forgot to include it, I updated the answer

Comment: no problem, thanks for your answer !